# mysqldump not creating table, then attempting to LOCK / ALTER the non-existing table

Tags: sql, magento, mysql

Having several issues with a mysqldump on mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.66, for unknown-linux-gnu (x86_64), first being:

A standard mysqldump is **not** creating a table, then attempting to LOCK / ALTER the non-existent table.

SQL query:

```
--Dumping data for table `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp`
LOCK TABLES  `catalog_product_incatalog_category_entitydex_price_cfg_opt_tmp` WRITE;
```

MySQL said:

```
Documentation
#1146 - Table 'group_high.catalog_product_incatalog_category_entitydex_price_cfg_opt_tmp' doesn't exist.
```

Any idea on how this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues in the past. And this answer might be similar to the "did you try turning it on". But how I have fixed it in the past is to close connection to DB then start again and make sure all the tables are there, and I can query that specific table. Then begin the MySQL. If it's still not outputting then you've narrowed the problem down to the dump.